# Open "parent.window.location.href" in new window (in Highcharts)?

Tags: highcharts, window

My Highchart graphic is being displayed in an iFrame. Now, I would like to open the link to the "definition" of the chart into a new window/new tab. This version here:

```
credits: 
{
    text: "Definition",
    href: "javascript:parent.window.location.href='http://www.xxxx'",
}
```

opens the definition into the main window, but not in a new one.

Does anyone have a tip how this would work?

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tested this, but I think you can use window.open rather than setting the current href:

```
href: "javascript:window.open('http://www.xxxx')",
```